# Difference between returning render_templates and jinja templtes in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have seen two ways to route HTML pages in Flask.

Either you declare a variable called template like so

```
def home():
    template = jinja_env.get_template('hello_form.html')
    return template.render()
```

or you just return the HTML templates

```
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)
```

is there a difference between the two if yes, what is it?

Comment: perhaps, just the filenames ;)

Comment: you did not intend to pass anything to a template in first example, right?

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak I just used the files as an example ;)

Comment: @Evgengy Pogrebnyak No, it was just an example i had, the parameter passed it did not matter

Comment: @supersam654 has a deep insight on it, very knowledgable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're effectively the same thing and you should probably use the second one because it's more "Flask-y" and may broadcast events about template rendering (although, chances are, you don't actually care about those events).

In Flask, [`render_template` is defined as](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/4309c7c6ea51e5797604c43ba858e5ebe1fb1674/flask/templating.py#L122-L135):

```
def render_template(template_name_or_list, **context):
    """Renders a template from the template folder with the given
    context.
    :param template_name_or_list: the name of the template to be
                                  rendered, or an iterable with template names
                                  the first one existing will be rendered
    :param context: the variables that should be available in the
                    context of the template.
    """
    ctx = _app_ctx_stack.top
    ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
                   context, ctx.app)
```

The first argument is a slightly [more abstract version of `jinja_env.get_template`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Environment.get_or_select_template). Similarly, `context` are the named variables that are accessible from the template. Finally, [`_render` is defined right above](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/4309c7c6ea51e5797604c43ba858e5ebe1fb1674/flask/templating.py#L113-L119) as:

```
def _render(template, context, app):
    """Renders the template and fires the signal"""

    before_render_template.send(app, template=template, context=context)
    rv = template.render(context)
    template_rendered.send(app, template=template, context=context)
    return rv
```

The first and third lines are broadcasting events that a template is getting rendered. If you have any Flask extensions, they may be listening for those events and doing extra things. Finally, the middle line is the exact same `template.render()` you were calling yourself.

Comment: Very nice explanation sir.